# How can I click a link in a webpage in Rselenium?

Tags: r

I know this should be simple, I'm just not sure why this is not working! Please help. I have the following code:

```
RSelenium::startServer()
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                  , port = 4444
                  , browserName = "safari"
)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~mshok002/")
```

Next, I need to click on the link "Teaching" at the top of the page and I'm stuck here. The html code is here at the following I'm just not sure how to find it using remDr$findElement. How can I search for both the link "Teaching" and html code "Teaching.html"?

```
<a href="Teaching.html">Teaching</a>
```

Thanks much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out how to do it so I'm posting my answer which may be helpful for others. I came up with two approaches:
First:

```
remDr$navigate("Teaching.html")
```

Second:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector',"Teaching")
webElem$clickElement()
```

Answer (score -3):

Another way you can do is -- go to the page using rselenium

right click the link and select unique selector and then use clickElement()